# Ebay upload CSV: Missing Brand when is already filled, also with MPN

Tags: csv, sftp, ebay-api, ebay-sdk

i'm trying from days to fix this issue without success on Ebay. Tried also other similar questions.

I need to upload an high volume on products (12.000) using CSV format and SFTP upload, but after some errors resolutions, now i get the following:

```
FAILED | ERROR | 21919303 | Manca la specifica dell'oggetto Marca. Aggiungi Marca all'inserzione, inserisci un valore valido e riprova.
```

That you can translate with: "The item specific "Marca" (Brand) is missing. Please add a valid value and try again."

But in my CSV i already added Brand, MPN and UPC (with "Does not apply" value) and still this error.

What can i do to fix it?
Thanks a lot.